# how can I see what script initiated a specific mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am experiencing some troubles with certain MySQL queries. In trying to fix it, I need to find out what files exactly create these queries. Is there a way to see this in the MySQL log files or through some other, simpler way?

The only thing I can see is the time, the user and the query itself, but not which script has initiated this query. This is what I am trying to find out.

Answer (score 0):

I found this class that could help you on achieve that.

```
class LoggerPDO extends PDO
{
    function query()
    {
        return $this->logger('query', func_get_args());
    }

    private function logger($method, $args)
    {
        // log query
        debug_print_backtrace();
        // push to parent
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, 'parent::' . $method), $args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Useful but unfortunately I can't implement it if I don't know the file that creates the problem. I am trying to debug a program that wasn't written by myself. It has about 1000 files and I don't know which of them create the bugged queries I am having trouble with. Any other idea?

Comment: btw, i found this article that could help, im not sure though because im in the middle of something now, but take a look at it: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/getting_started_dtrace_saha.html